# How do I append a div to another div with a specific id within the scope of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build up my DOM using simple methods that iterate though an XML model.

I cannot seem to reference `<div id='content'>` in order to append my content. I have the following function to create a panel:

```
function getPanelTemplate(controlData)
{
    var header = $('<div/>', 
        {
            'class' :'panel panel-heading',
            'id'    :'header',
            'text'  : $(controlData).attr('label')
        }
    )

    var body = $('<div/>', 
        {
            'class' :'panel panel-body',
            'id'    :'content'
        }
    )                

    var template = $('<div/>', 
        {
            'class':'panel panel-default',
        }
    )

    template.append(header)
    template.append(body)
    return template
}
```

I then have another function that calls this one with which I then want to add content into the 'content' div:

```
function createCheckBox(controlData)
{
    var panel = getPanelTemplate(controlData)
    var checkBox = $('<input type="checkbox"/>')

    //panel.content.append(checkbox)
    //panel.getElementByID('content').append(checkbox)
    //$(panel, '#content').append(checkbox)

    return panel
}
```

None of the three commented-out lines of code have worked for me. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Also, I think that jQuery only has a global scope. Am I right in thinking that I can't use jQuery inside a function referencing *only* the local variable?

Comment: Your third one would be the one you want to use, but you have your [arguments switched around](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1): `$('#content',panel).append(checkbox)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you've called your var `checkBox` and you're appending something which is called `checkbox`. So, even though you would have the correct implementation it wouldn't have worked because of that.

To fix your problem you can do this:

```
$(panel).find('#content').append(checkBox);
```

Using the above code you're looking for an element with the ID `content` within your `panel` element.

Comment: Since IDs must be unique, this would suffice:  `$('#content').append(checkBox);`

Comment: @RickHitchcock You're correct, they *should* be unique. That doesn't always happen though.

Comment: Thanks newmediafreak - super quick response - very much appreciated!  

RE Unique ID's  -  I am trying to convert an application I have written in Flex and so the ID 'content' will not be unique, however the parent of the content div will have a unique ID so I will in time reference this parent, then reference the 'content' from there ;)

Comment: @Beaker You could change it into a class if that's possible. So instead of `#content` use `.content`.

Comment: Unique IDs are a requirement in HTML4 and HTML5, although Chrome and IE (at least) allow you to target non-unique IDs within elements.  That may not be the case for future versions of the browsers.